# Custom Fonts on Opera Mobile Emulator

Tags: mobile, fonts, android-emulator, emulation, opera

I am working on a Responsive Coming Soon page. It looks quite fine on several devices like iPad or iPhone, but to test them on multiple platform I am using **Opera Mobile Emulator**.

It is not detecting the Custom Font retrieved from Google Font API used in CSS. It's rather showing the fallback font come as default given within CSS. Problem is within emulator I can not see if the font has been loaded or not using the resources timeline.

Was testing the Emulator for Samsung Galazy Nexus.

What might be the reason behind this? Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Web fonts (local as well as through Google Web Fonts) are working for me on the emulator. Can you share the page if possible?

Comment: [Emulator](http://cl.ly/2f1C0M3H1X311l2I3x0l) is the emulator screen. But tested the site on real device on Android Galaxy S2. It's working well on real device. [Real Device](http://instagr.am/p/Jm9mZxHxCb/) - Really Strange.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell from this page: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/opera-mini-web-content-authoring-guidelines/#typography Opera mini doesn't support custom fonts, specifically:

> setting font-family will have no effect